# Devlookup : A Search tool designed for developers

Tags: app, questions, answers

[image: Devlookup : A Search tool for developers]

### About

**[Devlookup](http://devlookup.io) is a search tool designed for developers.**
It aggregates results from the most important development websites, using Bing as the backend engine.

The main goal is to improve resource **search productivity**, by providing more detailed information on results than classical search engines and overall **a better search experience**.